# spring security saml Pre-configured SP metadata location

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

According documentation for [SP Pre-configured metadata](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-sp-import), I am advised to put the SP metadata in:

```
WEB-INF/classes/metadata/
```

which doesn't even exist.

Is it possibile to store SP metadata alongside IdP metadata in:

```
src/main/resources/metadata/
```

?

Comment: It does exist in the sample application, have a look at examples there.

Comment: Thank you for the patience. Are we talking about the `sample/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` dir in the git-cloned project?

Comment: I misunderstood your question at first, it's clear when re-reading now.. too much multi-tasking. You can of course add it to src/main/resources/metadata/, it will end up in WEB-INF/classes/metadata after packaging to war archive.

Comment: Fine, thank you, problem solved.

Comment: @473183469 I am trying to follow the same documentation but am unable to use pre-configured metadata. Can you share a sample or guide me on how to get it working?